# Autolayout animation - Do i use the constant value?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I took the belated plunge to look at `Autolayout`. Normally I'd animate based on a UIView's frame (i.e I'd have used the following):

```
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.buttonArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];

for (int i = 0;i<sortedArray.count;i++) {

    UIButton * theButton = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:i *0.05 usingSpringWithDamping:10 initialSpringVelocity:20 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [theButton setFrame:frameToAnimateTo];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Am I right in thinking that I now have to animate based on the Constant property of a buttons constraint?

```
 NSArray *sortedArray = [self.ButtonHorizonalConstraints sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];

 for (int i = 0;i  'less than' sortedArray.count;i++) {

     NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
     UIButton * theButton = constraint.firstItem;

     constraint.constant = toShow?0:-theButton.frame.size.width;
     [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:i *(toShow?0.1:0.05) usingSpringWithDamping:10 initialSpringVelocity:toShow?20:-20
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     } completion:nil]; }
```

The end result I get is what I desire, but something doesn't seem right in terms of how to code is constructed.

Comment: I think you don't need to `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` Your code is ok. This is the way animations with autolayout work. Set the constraint's constant value and then call layoutIfNeeded inside an animation block.

Comment: @Thedude Thanks buddy, at least i am on the right lines - thats good. :)